# TTL for PTR records on Windows 2003 Server DNS

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, ptr-record

When I look at the TTL (Time to Live) for PTR records (Reverse Lookup Zone) on one of our Windows 2003 DNS servers I see some are at 15 minutes, others are at 20.  They have "Delete this record when it becomes stale" checked.

- These PTR records are for workstations that get IPs from Windows DHCP, so I think that creates the PTR records dynamically?
- How is TTL for these records set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workstations (Windows 2000, XP, and above) in a domain will register themselves in DNS.  They will create an A record and a PTR record.  A DHCP server can also be configured to created records on the behalf of older clients.

You can control the behavior including the TTL via [group policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294785).

See:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294785
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816592